# Two correct answers from the array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a Polish quiz with irregular verbs, I have a problem in that, for example, to the word "be" in one of the inputs match the two words "was" and "were" how to do it to fit 2 words?

```js
const foo = () => {
  var words = [
  {INF: 'be',  SIM: 'was', PAR: 'been', PL: 'być', },
  {INF: 'begin', SIM: 'began', PAR: 'begun', PL: 'zaczynać'},
  {INF: 'break', SIM: 'broke', PAR: 'broken', PL: 'łamać'},
  {INF: 'bring', SIM: 'brought', PAR: 'brought', PL: 'przynosić'},
  {INF: 'buy',  SIM: 'bought', PAR: 'bought', PL: 'kupować'},
  {INF: 'build', SIM: 'built', PAR: 'built', PL: 'budować'},
  {INF: 'choose', SIM: 'chose', PAR: 'chosen', PL: 'wybierać'},
  {INF: 'come', SIM: 'came', PAR: 'come', PL: 'przyjść'},
  {INF: 'cost', SIM: 'cost', PAR: 'cost', PL: 'kosztować'},
  {INF: 'cut', SIM: 'cut', PAR: 'cut', PL: 'ciąć'},
  ]

  const word = document.getElementById('word');
 const test = document.getElementById('test');
  const InputInf = document.getElementById('InputInf');
  const InputSim = document.getElementById('InputSim');
  const InputPar = document.getElementById('InputPar');
 const submit = document.getElementById('submit');

  let randomWord = null;

  const num = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  const postWord = () => { randomWord = word.innerText = words[num()].PL; }

  postWord();

  submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const inputValueInf = InputInf.value;
    const inputValueSim = InputSim.value;
    const inputValuePar = InputPar.value;
    const matchingInf = words.find(word => word.PL === randomWord).INF;
    const matchingSim = words.find(word => word.PL === randomWord).SIM;
    const matchingPar = words.find(word => word.PL === randomWord).PAR;

    if (inputValueInf === matchingInf  && inputValueSim === matchingSim  &&
    inputValuePar === matchingPar) {
     postWord();
       InputInf.value = '';
      InputSim.value = '';
      InputPar.value = '';
        answerInf.innerText = '';
        answerSim.innerText = '';
        answerPar.innerText = '';
      return;
    }

    if(inputValueInf !== matchingInf){
        answerInf.textContent = "[ "+matchingInf+" ]";
          document.getElementById("answerInf").className = "answer";
      }   else{
            document.getElementById("answerInf").className = "display-none";
      }

    if(inputValueSim !== matchingSim){
        answerSim.textContent = "[ "+matchingSim+" ]";
          document.getElementById("answerSim").className = "answer";
      }   else{
            document.getElementById("answerSim").className = "display-none";
      }

    if(inputValuePar !== matchingPar){
        answerPar.textContent = "[ "+matchingPar+" ]";
          document.getElementById("answerPar").className = "answer";
      }   else{
            document.getElementById("answerPar").className = "display-none";
      }
    }, false);
};

window.onload = foo();
```

```html
<div id="quiz">
<div id="word">Zaczynać</div>
<input type="text" id="InputInf" class="quiz-input" placeholder="Infinitive">
<input type="text" id="InputSim" class="quiz-input" placeholder="Simple Past">
<input type="text" id="InputPar" class="quiz-input" placeholder="Past Participle">

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Check">

<div class="ugh">
  <div id="answerInf" class="answer"></div>
  <div id="answerSim" class="answer"></div>
  <div id="answerPar" class="answer"></div>
</div>
```

If someone prefer a jsFiddle: [code](https://jsfiddle.net/zxzc0/wxs1Lok9/)

Comment: What do you mean by to 'fit 2 words'? Do you want to check for either one?

Comment: In a quiz there are sometimes two good answers, I want it to be possible to add two words as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way you would do it is by setting the field as arrays containing the correct answers.
Here's an example:

```js
  var words = [
  {INF: 'be',  SIM: ['was', 'were'], PAR: 'been', PL: 'być', },
  {INF: 'begin', SIM: 'began', PAR: 'begun', PL: 'zaczynać'},
  {INF: 'break', SIM: 'broke', PAR: 'broken', PL: 'łamać'},
  {INF: 'bring', SIM: 'brought', PAR: 'brought', PL: 'przynosić'},
  {INF: 'buy',  SIM: 'bought', PAR: 'bought', PL: 'kupować'},
  {INF: 'build', SIM: 'built', PAR: 'built', PL: 'budować'},
  {INF: 'choose', SIM: 'chose', PAR: 'chosen', PL: 'wybierać'},
  {INF: 'come', SIM: 'came', PAR: 'come', PL: 'przyjść'},
  {INF: 'cost', SIM: 'cost', PAR: 'cost', PL: 'kosztować'},
  {INF: 'cut', SIM: 'cut', PAR: 'cut', PL: 'ciąć'},
  ];
  
  var userAnswer = "was";
  var ifn = "be";
  
  var words = words.find(word => word.INF === ifn);
  
  var isCorrect = Array.isArray(words.SIM) ? words.SIM.indexOf(userAnswer) > -1 : words.SIM == userAnswer;
  
  console.log(isCorrect);
```

Comment: How should I integrate your code into my code? maybe it can be done somehow in this way on the principle to do it in such a way, for example, {INF: 'be',  SIM: 'was', SIMM:'were' PAR: 'been', PL: 'być', }, and later add in if, e.g. inputValueInf === matchingInf  && inputValueSim === matchingSim  ||  inputValueSim === matchingSimm&&
    inputValuePar === matchingPar ?

Comment: How you implement it is your choice. My answer is a guide to how efficiently do multiple correct answers like you asked. If I was you I would try to run my example and debug if you don't understand to see what's happening. If you don't understand the code let me know and I'll comment it. The reason I didn't is because I thought it's self explanatory.